# MariaDB failing steps to reset lost root password

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mac-os-x

I'm running a local copy of MariaDB on OS X from Homebrew. It's working fine, but I've forgotten my root password (yeah, I know) and the usual reset is failing like this:

```
$ mysqld_safe ‐‐skip-grant-tables &
[1] 22120
$ 190818 13:47:37 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mycomputername.err'.
190818 13:47:37 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var
```

so far, so good? However, I get no mysql prompt, and hitting return brings me back to my CL prompt. Then (as a root user) entering:

`mysql -u root`

gives:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

So I'm not getting in without a password and I can't proceed with the standard password reset.

The error logs shows:

```
2019-08-18 12:38:44 4527658432 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-18 12:38:44 4527658432 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
/usr/local/bin/mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is '‐‐skip-grant-tables').
2019-08-18 12:38:44 4527658432 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I cannot `update user set plugin='' where User='root';` as I can't get a mysql shell.

---

### UPDATE:

error log after upgrading and trying skip-grant-tables again:

```
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=4766241
2019-08-20 16:01:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Upgrading redo log: 2*50331648 bytes; LSN=4766259
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 50331648 bytes
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 50331648 bytes
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=4766259
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 4766259; transaction id 47107
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALU
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
2019-08-20 16:01:07 6 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-08-20 16:01:07 6 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.6-MariaDB'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew
2019-08-20 16:01:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190820 16:01:07
```

`mysql_upgrade` gave:

```
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

This is a Homebrew installation on MariaDB.

Comment: You probably want to run `mysqld_safe` as the root user (via `sudo`), which you don't seem to be doing in your example.

Comment: Was there a recent upgrade?  Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: `mysqld_safe` still wants my password… I’ve held off an upgrade because I need to try a MySQL dump from the production site into my local MariaDB and the versions are already too far apart for comfort

Comment: Have you tried running (as OS root) `mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`? The error message appears to say `mysqld_safe` has tried to start `mysqld` with too many arguments, so by circumventing `mysqld_safe` and running `mysqld` directly, perhaps you won't see that problem. If that still doesn't work, let's see the error log you get now.

Comment: You need to run `mysql_upgrade` _before_ doing anything with it.

Comment: done the upgrade, problem persists…

Comment: Latest: $ mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 10194
Daves-MacBook-Pro:~ daveeveritt$ 2019-08-20 16:01:22 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.6-MariaDB) starting as process 10194 ...
2019-08-20 16:01:22 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-08-20 16:01:22 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/usr/local/var/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 35. Will retry for 30 seconds

Comment: @dbdemon just upgraded, tried again, see above comment and new error log appended to question - thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that you were definitely running the `mysqld` and `mysqld_safe` commands as the OS root user?

Comment: I have root access: sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 11599
$ sudo mysql -u root
Password: (blank)
Sorry, try again.